# Reading plain text file on Android 11 without user interaction from uninstallation-persistent memory

Tags: android, android-11, scoped-storage

I have an app which communicates with BLE device and reads the data. The App pairs with the BLE peripheral and saves the Mac Id of the device for reading the data later. This device info is also stored in a plain text file for persisting the paired device, since uninstallation of the app still keeps the peripheral paired in Bluetooth Manager. The file reading and writing works well with MediaStore APIs. But when app is uninstalled, the ownership of the file is lost. On Android 11, how could this file be read without user interaction and without `MANAGE_STORAGE_ACCESS` permission (not core functionality)?